# How to use a local image as service in a docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I want to use a locally build docker image in my `docker-machine`

I have a swarm cluster set up with docker-machine and like to use locally build docker image. after ssh into a one node with `docker-machine ssh manager`

I want to start a service with a locally build image such as

```
docker service create --name=database --publish=3306:3306 <localDataBaseImage>
```

How can this be achieved

Answer (score 2):

You need to push the image to [docker hub](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#extended-description)/ [local docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-a-local-registry) and use that image while creating containers in docker machine.

- if you have the image in docker hub, you need to perform `docker login` in the docker-machine
- if you have the image in local registry, create docker-machine with `insecure-registries` option pointing to the url of your registry.